# Why UITextField added whitespaces at the end of inputed strings?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitextfield, swift5

After spending time for debuging I recognized that UITextField adds whitespaces to my strings pasted from  clip board.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var input: String
        let newString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)   // newString = "123"
        if let oldString = textField.text {                                      // oldString = "456"
            input = oldString
            input.insert(contentsOf: newString, at: input.index(input.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location))  // rang.location = 2, input = "4 123 56" but it supposed to be "412356"
        } else {
            input = newString
        }
        return true  
}
```

I have two questions:
1- Why it happens only by pasting at second and more times?
2- How can I avoid adding these whitespaces to my pasted strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably observing the effects of the `smartInsertDeleteType` property. You can change that like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.smartInsertDeleteType = .no
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem and questions for this behaviour.